# How to stop a agent process, when the pipeline be canceled manually?

Tags: python, azure-pipelines

I have an azure pipeline, it has a step will run a python script, this script has a loop statement (while True), it will monitor a job status, if the job finished or failed, the loop will stop and script will finished, and the pipeline will keep running until the script finished. Now, I have a question, if I canceled this pipeline manually, the agent will received a canceled command, but the script will still keep running. After a while, the pipeline will failed, the error message like below:
*##[error]We stopped hearing from agent ***. Verify the agent machine is running and has a healthy network connection. Anything that terminates an agent process, starves it for CPU, or blocks its network access can cause this error.*
How to stop this script while the agent received a canceled command? Anyone can please help me? I would be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

You can call [Builds - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0#buildresult) to get [build status](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0#buildstatus) inside the loop and if it is `cancelling` break the loop.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/how-to/call-rest-api?view=azure-devops) you have documentation how to start with [Azure DevOps Rest Api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/how-to/call-rest-api?view=azure-devops).

Comment: Thanks, but my code is Python, so maybe I need a python API, but I can't found it.

Comment: This is just regular REST API you can consume it in every language. But if you want you can use dedicated [one](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-devops-python-api) nad [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61343965/2347999) you have an example how to use regular one.