# Using the Azure DevOps Python API to create a new work-item

Tags: python, api, azure-devops

Similar to the question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60441473/creating-a-workitem-in-azure-devops-via-python/76102850#76102850), I am trying to manage Azure DevOps work items via python.

The accepted answer refers to the official [Azure DevOps Python API docs](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-python-api) and some [sample code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-devops-cli-extension/blob/768aff8971aad2e194fa26d796d47b3a67292b4e/azure-devops/azext_devops/dev/boards/work_item.py#L24) which seems like it might be out of date.

Here is a simplified version of the script I am trying to run:

```
from azure.devops.connection import Connection
from azure.devops.v7_1.work_item_tracking import JsonPatchOperation
from msrest.authentication import BasicAuthentication

personal_access_token = "MY_PAT"
organization_url = f'https://dev.azure.com/{MY_ORG}'

# Create a connection to the org
credentials = BasicAuthentication('', personal_access_token)
connection = Connection(base_url=organization_url, creds=credentials)

core_client = connection.clients.get_core_client()  # core client --> used to get project
project = core_client.get_project(MY_PROJECT_ID)
wit_client = connection.clients.get_work_item_tracking_client()  # work item tracking client

# this code is recycled from the azure example code posted above
def _create_work_item_field_patch_operation(op, field, value):
    path = '/fields/{field}'.format(field=field)
    return _create_patch_operation(op=op, path=path, value=value)

def _create_patch_operation(op, path, value):
    patch_operation = JsonPatchOperation()
    patch_operation.op = op
    patch_operation.path = path
    patch_operation.value = value
    patch_operation._from = None
    return patch_operation

patch_document = []
patch_document.append(_create_work_item_field_patch_operation('add', 'System.Title', "Testing"))
patch_document.append(_create_work_item_field_patch_operation('add', 'System.Description', "Hoping to create a new work item."))
wit_client.create_work_item(document=patch_document, project=project, type="Bug")
```

When I execute this code, I get the following error:

```
azure.devops.exceptions.AzureDevOpsClientRequestError: Operation returned a 400 status code.
```

I am wondering if anybody has insight into why I am receiving a 400 status code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the code above was that I was passing in the `TeamProject` object as opposed to the project name or UUID.

So for example, it should be this:

```
...

wit_client.create_work_item(document=patch_document, project=MY_PROJECT_ID, type="Bug")
```

Doing so will result in the work item to be created as expected.